# Symfony2.8 : Page too much time to load but without response

Tags: php-7, symfony-2.8

I have a Symfony2.8 project, when i load the main page it took too much time to load but i got `symfony2 FatalErrorException in PDOStatement.php line 91`

i've follow the code on `app_dev.php` on the line when handle the request(`$response = $kernel->handle($request);` ) it blocks !

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = RequestFactory::createFromGlobals('host_with_path'); // before: $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request); // the error here !
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

when i try to execute symfony `doctrine schema update --force` it also blocked !
my symfony version is 2.8 running on php7.2

Nothing was writed on the trace !

So please how can i fix this problem.

Comment: We're going to need a little bit more information to come up with a sensible answer. Do you get a stack trace? Which request is the kernel handling? What's in the request handler?

Comment: i've edited my question, hope it helps

Comment: It's not enough information still.. The error is talking about a problem with a `PDOStatement`, which is sql-related, but this code does not show the sql code. What happens when the request is handled? *That* is where the key to the solution is.